# Publishing to Azure Virtual Machine from Visual Studio

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2019, azure-virtual-machine

I am attempting to publish a Visual Studio 2019 project to an Azure Virtual Machine for the first time.  I right click the Project and select Publish.  Then choose Azure Virtual Machines for the target, sign into my Azure account and choose the virtual machine name off the list.  Once I click OK a message comes up that says

> The specified virtual machine does not have a domain name associated
>   with any public IP address

My virtual machine has a live public IP address and a DNS name is assigned to it.  If I go to a web browser I can type in `http://'ip address'`  or `http://'dns name'` and both will load the hosted website.

Any ideas on what else I can try?

Comment: Any luck ? I'm having the same issue

Answer (score 1):

If can help, check network configuration on Azure (NSG and DNS).
Also, verify that Web Management Console is also installed.

[Web App on Azure VM](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/deploy-web-app-in-azure-vm-using-visual-studio/)